Finding value of $\displaystyle \sum^{10}_{r=1}r\binom{10}{r}\binom{10}{10-r}$

Then value of


$\displaystyle \binom{10}{1}^2+2\binom{10}{2}^2+3\binom{10}{3}^2+\cdots +10\binom{10}{10}^2=$

I am trying to solve it using Combinational Argument
We can write it as
$\displaystyle 1\cdot \binom{10}{1}\cdot \binom{10}{9}+2\cdot \binom{10}{2}\cdot \binom{10}{8}+\cdots +10\cdot \binom{10}{10}\cdot \binom{10}{0}=\sum^{10}_{r=1}r\binom{10}{r}\binom{10}{10-r}$
For left side: We have total $20$ students in which $10$ are boys and $10$ are girls and we have to select $10$ student and out of these selected boys student one is class monitor  Now we have to select $r$ boys out of $10$ and $10-r$ from remaining $10$ girls
And for right side , selecting $10$ students out of total $20$ student and anyone $1$ is class monitor from selected student.
So total ways $\displaystyle \binom{20}{10}\cdot 10$
But answer given is $\displaystyle 5\binom{20}{10}$
I did not understand where I miss, Help me , Thanks

Related.

Two remarks about your approach. 1) Where did that $10\cdot\binom{20}{10}$ come from? 2) The number of ways, call it $B$, of selecting 10 students and a girl as a monitor, is closely related to the number $A$ you want to calculate. Have you tried simplifying $A+B$ and going from there?

The $r$ doesn't allow the class monitor to be chosen from either sex.  It has to be chosen from the boys.  Dividing by 2 allows you to factor out the choice of boy/girl monitor.

Your "For left side" says the class monitor is out of the selected boys. While in your "for right side", anyone $1$ is class monitor from selected student, regardless of the gender.

This is a megaduplicate: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C OR content%3A%24%5Csum%5En_%7Bk%3D1%7Dk%5Cbinom nk%5Cbinom n%7Bn-k%7D%24&p=1 (sorry I don't know how to fix the link but you can copy-paste it into your browser)

Approach0 <- Anne Bauval's link.

This question is similar to: Combination proof $\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}^2=n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Note that $r\binom{10}{r}=10\binom{9}{r-1}$ for $r\ge 1$.

Let's review your statement first. When you consider the left side, you require that the monitor must be a boy. However, when you conclude that total ways is $10\binom{20}{10}$, anyone can be a monitor. Thus, the monitor can also be a girl, so your answer is not right.
Actually, your answer is very close to the right one. Since we have the number of boys and that of girls is the same, so the total ways that the monitor is a boy equals the total ways that the monitor is a girl. Therefore, the left side is exactly the half of total ways that anyone can be a monitor, i.e. $5\binom{20}{10}$.
